# How to custom control base on other control

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, win-universal-app

I want to make a custom control that base on TextBox but when I set it's style and it have not enter OnApplyTemplate.

I write a custom control `Foo`

```
public class Foobar : TextBox
{
    public Foobar()
    {
        DefaultStyleKey = typeof(Foobar);
    }

    protected override void OnApplyTemplate()
    { //breakpoint have not enter
        base.OnApplyTemplate();
    }
}
```

And I write the style in Generic.xaml

```
<Style x:Key="Foobar" TargetType="TextBox"></Style>
<Style TargetType="view:Foobar">

</Style>
```

For UWP have no `x:Type` ,I should write the base on for static Resource

```
<Style x:Key="Foobar" TargetType="TextBox"></Style>
<Style TargetType="view:Foobar" BasedOn="{StaticResource Foobar}">

</Style>
```

But both code did not work.

I write it to mainPage.xaml but it did not show.

I try write it in resource

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <viewModel:ViewModel x:Key="ViewModel"></viewModel:ViewModel>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Themes/Generic.xaml"></ResourceDictionary>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

But it did not work.

Comment: I dont want to copy the templete in RichEditBox.

Comment: You mention RichEditBox yet your template and styles targets TextBox... which is it then?

Comment: @PedroLamas I want say such as RichEditBox.

Comment: Have you tried adding the template you're expecting to your generic Style (i.e. <Setter.Template> ...Your control template here... </Setter.Template>

Also, you should not have to reference the generic.xaml

Comment: @JamesCroft I try set and didt set it but both have nothing.